# can't find ipython notebook in the app list of anaconda launcher

Tags: python, anaconda, launcher

I download anaconda launcher and successfully launched the Ipython notebook, then the next time I open the anaconda launcher I couldn't find the ipython notebook in the app list

Answer (score 0):

I reinstall the program again, the problem was that I accidentally have 2 version of the same program